# Completely ignore directory in webpack

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack

I have my application with the following structure

```
./
client/
    .. some files
server/
    server.js
widgets/
    .. some files
webpack.conf.js
```

Now, I would like `webpack` to ignore completely contents of the `server/` directory. I know, that webpack is running the files from `server.js` because when launching it on my own - I get EADDRINUSE. Webpack runs the `server.js` file.

I have tried the following

- Using `include` and `exclude` inside the `module.loaders`
- Using `module.noParse`
- Picking client and widgets in `resolve.root`

Seems that all of above actions are performed after webpack reuires the `server.js` file. Because if I put invalid param in for example `module.loaders` and I put syntax error in `server.js` I first see the syntax error and then the invalid param message in webpack.

Here's my webpack config

```
var path = require('path')
console.log(path.resolve(__dirname, 'client'))

module.exports = {
    entry: './client/index.jsx',
    output: {
        publicPath: 'http://localhost:8090/assets'
    },
    module: {
      loaders: [{
          noParse: /server/,
          test: /\.jsx$/,
          loader: 'jsx-loader?insertPragma=React.DOM&harmony'
        }, {
          test: /\.scss$/,
          loader: 'style!css!sass'
        }
      ]
    },
    resolve: {
      root: [
        path.resolve(__dirname, 'client')
      ]
      extensions: ['', '.js', '.jsx']
    }
}
```

Launching webpack with:

```
webpack-dev-server --progress --colors --port 8090
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Webpack would only try to bundle files from server if you require them within your client. And there is no way that webpack is trying to execute your code.

So probably problem is not about webpack at all. I assume you have server already running on this port. Try to run webpack-dev-server on a different port.

Comment: Then you had running server on this port for sure :)